# React Native android App refused to run on Emulator

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

I did all the steps to create a react native application , but when it came to running the App it shows me this Error below in the image , what could be the problem.[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure your emulator is run (i recommended using genymotion), and also ensure you have been to configure your system with android environment. You can follow step by step in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.23/docs/android-setup.html).

Comment: what about using a physical device ?

Comment: Yes it does not matter, you can use emulator or physical device but if you use phisical device the minimum version supported to build Android apps is 4.0.3 (API level 15).

Comment: Am using a physical device Version of marshmallow 6.0 but still the same message

Comment: have you setting your environment like the documentation? i have updated the answer to setup your environment from other article that i found.